# 'AimTarget_GetTagPos: cannot find tag[j_helmet] on entity' Error on MW3

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I just got a 'AimTarget_GetTagPos: cannot find tag[j_helmet] on entity' error on COD: MW3 and I was booted from the game.

I am aware the same question was asked, but I wanted to re-ask it because

A) I am playing this through Backwards compatibility on XBO

B) The answer to the other question said someone was hacking and removed their head model, and I'm 99% sure you can't hack on Xbox and

C) This is MW3 and not MW2 like the other question.

A couple minutes before I was kicked and received this error, I was lagging and boomeranging around the map a lot, so any answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: A comment on your B) No system is unhackable. There are constant reports of hacked servers, even for consoles.

Answer (score -3):

Trust me, someone hacked the lobby. And this is coming from someone who used to play a lot of MW3 a few years back.

Comment: This isn't an open forum, this is a QNA site. This doesn't answer the question